# Stacking three DIVs horizontally making the middle one scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 1) Header, 2)Left  Panel, 3) Middle Div1 4) Middle Div2 & a 5)Right Div

```
<div id="HEADER">
</div>

<div id="LEFT_PANEL">
</div>

<div id="DIV1_mid">
</div>

<div id="DIV2_mid">
some dynamic content
</div>

<div id="RIGHT_PANEL">
```

The left panel remains of a pre-defined height. The middle_div2 div displays stuff okay till the left panel's height. Once the content of middle_div2 exceeds the height of left-panel, the content sticks to the left of the page, below left panel. help me make the middle_div2 scrollable!!!!!
Please help me make it okay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `max-height`  and add `overflow:scroll` for `#DIV2_mid`

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3F3T5/)

Comment: this answer is probably the most complete so far

Comment: Thanks @Tilwin That works. :) Although if I had to, say, dynamically increase the left panel's height, as the dynamic content in #DIV2_MID increases, WITHOUT putting a scroll on DIV2_MID, what could be done? I burst my head upon this, but could not find a suitable solution.

Comment: @user3477763 the closest i came for now is something like this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3F3T5/5/) but the problem is #DIV_MID! should have an `auto` height (depending on its content) or `height` set in `px`, it can't have size in `%` since the parent doesn't have a height set (`height:auto`) But this seems to be interesting, how about posting a new question, you might find interesting answers and  some up votes and as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make content of a div scrollable you can use this inside the CSS:

```
#DIV2_mid {
   overflow:scroll;
}
```